# Measuring connectivity between clusters in an organizational network in R

Tags: r, networks, social-network

I'm trying to conceptualize a network analysis problem and figure out where to start in terms of analysis techniques in R. Apologies as I'm fairly new to all this.

Basically, I have a employee network for an organization which spans multiple geographies. I want to define metrics to calculate how well the nodes in a specific geography are connected to the nodes in geographies other than its own.

Also, I am looking for any libraries/ functions that already exist in R to perform such calculations. I understand there is a wealth of network analysis techniques out there, but I'm at a loss where to start really.

Comment: http://www.pnas.org/content/103/23/8577.full Modularity is one option

Answer (score 1):

The [Krackhardt ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krackhardt_E/I_Ratio), also known as the E-I ratio, provides a measurement of "the relative density of internal connections within a social group compared to the number of connections that group has to the external world." If I understand your question correctly, this is exactly what you are looking for.

You could calculate the average Krackhardt ratio for nodes in each geographic location, and compare them against each other.

There is a short implementation in R here:
https://rpubs.com/pjmurphy/300606